# Galois groups permutes the roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $L:K$ is a finite extension and $G(L:K)$ denotes the Galois group of $L:K$.

Since $L:K$ is finite it is algebraic and therefore any element of $a\in L$ is the root of some polynomial $f\in K[x]$.

The Galois group consists of permutations of $L$ that permute roots of $f$.

My question is do the permutations of the Galois group when applied to $a$ give all the roots of $f$?

I ask this because in my notes for one particular proof it mentions the set $\{\sigma(a): \sigma \in G(L:K)\}$ and says let the distinct elements of this set be $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Later in the proof it says if $\phi \in G(L:K)$ then $\phi(\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ i.e. $\phi$ permutes the $a_i$’s.

I can’t see how $\phi$ permutes these $a_i$’s. My logic was that since $a$ is a root of $f$ then $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ are roots of $f$ as elements of the Galois group permute roots. But unless these are ALL the roots of $f$ I can’t see how $\phi$ necessarily permutes these roots as why can’t $\phi$ map some $a_i$ to another root of $f$ not in this set?

Comment: So the set of $a_i$’s is subgroup of $L$ because $\phi_1(a) {\phi_2}^{-1}(a) =\phi_1{\phi_2}^{-1} (a) = \sigma (a)$ for some $\sigma \in G(L:K)$.

Comment: But as this is a subgroup of $L$ and not a subgroup of $G(L:K)$ does multiplying the subgroup by $\phi$ still give a bijection from the subgroup to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the important condition of $L/K$ being Galois, which is equivalent to being a normal and separable extensions, or that $|Aut(L/K)| = [L:K]$. Not all extensions are Galois. Further, the Galois group of a Galois extension $L/K$ is not simply the permutations of $L$ that permute the roots of some random polynomial $f$. The Galois group of $L/K$, $Gal(L/K) = Aut(L/K)$, which is the group of field automorphisms fixing the base field $K$.

Under these assumptions, it is a standard result of Galois theory that the Galois group acts transitively on the set of roots of any irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$.

Comment: I’m not necessarily working with a Galois extension. In my proof I’m trying to actually show the finite extension $L:K$ is Galois if the fixed field $L^{G(L:K)}=K$

Comment: I do know what the Galois group strictly is defined as. But it was more relevant to my problem here to recognise that these K-automorphisms of L permute the roots of a polynomial.

Comment: They don't always. In a non-Galois extension, you could have a polynomial $f$ irreducible over $K$ that has a root in $K$ but doesn't split in $K$. Consider $f(x) =x^3 - 2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Not all on the roots even lie in $K$, but $\sqrt[3]{2}$ does.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. In my question does $\phi$ permute the $a_i$‘s.

Comment: Elements of automorphism groups $Aut(L/K)$ will always permute the roots of any polynomial with coefficients from the base field $K$ as you should be able to convince yourself with an elementary argument. This permutation isn't always transitive unless the extension is Galois and the polynomial was irreducible.